# Как разместить код программы в нескольких регионах памяти?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, ld

Есть несколько регионов памяти

```
MEMORY
{
  rom1 (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0x00000000,    LENGTH = 256k
  rom2 (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x10000000,    LENGTH = 16M
  ram1 (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,    LENGTH = 64k
  ram2 (rwx)  : ORIGIN = 0x21000000,    LENGTH = 16M
}
```

Как разместить секции .text всех входных файлов в регионах памяти rom1 и rom2? В описании выходной секции можно указать только один регион памяти.

```
  .text :
  {
    *(.text)
  } > rom1
```